# Autolayout unable to satify constraint error not showing up in Console

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, swift3, xcode8

In **Xcode 8**, autolayout error message **"unable to satify constraints...."** is not showing up in console. Is there any way to turn on the same?

Comment: I do see those messages. Do you have disabled logs because Xcode 8 had this logs bug?

Comment: maybe... your layout is perfect :)

Comment: you can see any logs like: _UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable is OFF?

Answer (score 0):

If you can see any logs like:

```
_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable is OFF
```

Then, you can enable autolayout constraint error messages in debug console output as follows:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@(YES) forKey:@"_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable"];
```

Swift:

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey:"_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable")
```

Otherwise, you have no autolayout issue, so there is no warning.